# Code Organiser Programs

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know of any tools or easy methods to help re-arrange and organise source code files?

In particular, I am looking for a tool that can take a javascript file, with a number of  separate functions, and show me a list of the functions which I can then re-arrange in a more logical order, and have it shuffle the code around to match my new ordering?

Ideally, it would be something that is interactive, rather than a single tool I have to run by command-line, as the order may differ each time.

I'm sure these sorts of tools must exist, but I can never find them whenever I look.

I also suspect that it is something that could be built rather easily by someone with good knowledge of Javascript meta-programming (it might just be a case of 'eval'ing the input, and finding all the functions, then rendering them in a re-orderable list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one, a non-free, editor that I'm aware of so far.  I found it when I was duckduckgo'ing months ago.

http://www.yaldex.com/JSFactory_Pro.htm

*I've never tried it however.*

Comment: Marked as answer because I didn't want to just accept my own answer. I haven't tried the product, though.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up buying [WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) by JetBrains, which is a commercial product, but it has the ability to see an overview of the file structure, and to reorder statements, including function definitions easily.

This wasn't the reason I bought it, but I am satisfied that it also contains this functionality that I was seeking, so I am going to close this question for now.